# Package “No match for group package” when attempting to switch to Fedora 33

Tags: linux, unix, fedora

Hello I want to switch from Fedora 32 to Fedora 33 using the following commands:

```
sudo dnf upgrade --refresh
sudo dnf install dnf-plugin-system-upgrade
sudo dnf system-upgrade download --refresh --releasever=33
```

But I have the impression that I have a concern of packet conflic. Here is the result.

```
(base) ➜  ~ sudo dnf system-upgrade download --refresh --releasever=33

Before you continue ensure that your system is fully upgraded by running "dnf --refresh upgrade". Do you want to continue [y/N]: y
Docker CE Stable - x86_64                        61 kB/s | 3.5 kB     00:00    
Fedora 33 openh264 (From Cisco) - x86_64        1.2 kB/s | 989  B     00:00    
Fedora Modular 33 - x86_64                      253 kB/s |  25 kB     00:00    
Fedora Modular 33 - x86_64 - Updates            242 kB/s |  22 kB     00:00    
Fedora 33 - x86_64 - Test Updates                97 kB/s | 6.9 kB     00:00    
Fedora 33 - x86_64 - Updates                    109 kB/s | 7.8 kB     00:00    
Fedora 33 - x86_64                              254 kB/s |  25 kB     00:00    
packages for the GitHub CLI                     5.2 kB/s | 3.0 kB     00:00    
google-chrome                                    34 kB/s | 1.3 kB     00:00    
Node.js Packages for Fedora Linux 31 - x86_64    19 kB/s | 2.5 kB     00:00    
RPM Fusion for Fedora 33 - Free - Updates        15 kB/s | 6.5 kB     00:00    
RPM Fusion for Fedora 33 - Free                  87 kB/s | 8.0 kB     00:00    
RPM Fusion for Fedora 33 - Nonfree - Updates     16 kB/s | 7.6 kB     00:00    
RPM Fusion for Fedora 33 - Nonfree               19 kB/s | 8.2 kB     00:00    
TeamViewer - x86_64                             4.9 kB/s | 867  B     00:00    
Visual Studio Code                               18 kB/s | 3.0 kB     00:00    
no group 'arm-tools' from environment 'workstation-product-environment'
No match for group package "xorg-x11-drv-armsoc"
No match for group package "powerpc-utils"
No match for group package "lsvpd"
No match for group package "specialelite-fonts"
No match for group package "moyogo-molengo-fonts"
No match for group package "oflb-sportrop-fonts"...
Error: 
 Problem 1: package gstreamer1-devel-docs-1.16.2-2.fc32.noarch requires gstreamer1 = 1.16.2-2.fc32, but none of the providers can be installed
  - gstreamer1-1.16.2-2.fc32.i686 does not belong to a distupgrade repository
  - gstreamer1-1.16.2-2.fc32.x86_64 does not belong to a distupgrade repository
  - problem with installed package gstreamer1-devel-docs-1.16.2-2.fc32.noarch
 Problem 2: package python3-lxml-4.5.2-1.3.i586 requires python(abi) = 3.8, but none of the providers can be installed
  - python3-3.8.8-1.fc32.x86_64 does not belong to a distupgrade repository
  - problem with installed package python3-lxml-4.5.2-1.3.i586
(try to add '--skip-broken' to skip uninstallable packages)
```

Comment: Seems like there is a problem with `gstreamer1`. My advice has two options: One is to just use `--skip-broken` (as advised in the last line of your output) and let the overall system update happen. Use it like this: `sudo dnf system-upgrade download --skip-broken --refresh --releasever=33`. The second option would be to just uninstall `gstreamer1`, do the update and reinstall `gstreamer1`. Many times that can easily happen without breaking things.

Comment: I tried ```sudo dnf system-upgrade download --skip-broken --refresh --releasever=33``` and I have the same errors, when i try to remove ```gstreamer1``` It suggests that I delete 304 packages so I don't really want to ^^'.
any other solution ? :)

Comment: You need to run `dnf system-upgrade download --releasever=33 --allowerasing`. This will remove `gstreamer1`. Any packages that are missing afterward may need to be installed from the new repository. You might before starting take a disk backup image of the system disk and to be able to restore.